# How to capitalize initial word in lwuit textfield?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textfield

I have tried my textfield to have the very first letter to be capitalized with the following code :-

```
Form f = new Form();
TextField firstname = new TextField();
firstname.setConstraint(TextField.INITIAL_CAPS_SENTENCE);
f.addComponent(firstname);
f.show();
```

But this is not working.

What am I missing here? Can anybody suggest a correct way to achieve it?

Note : I am using LWUIT 1.5

**Edited**

This is how I finally did it with the help of Shai

```
public void insertChars(String c) {
    super.insertChars(c); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    if(super.getText()!=null && super.getText().length()>0){      
        super.setText((super.getText().substring(0,1).toUpperCase())+super.getText().substring(1, super.getText().length()));
    }else{
        super.setText(super.getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a qwerty J2ME device by any chance? If so this won't work since this only applies to the native side of the things.

You need to derive `TextField` and override insertChar() to implement this.

Comment: Yup, I am using a qwerty device. And i overrided the insertChar() to achieve this as you mentioned. Thanks Shai :)